# Pivot table not comparing January current year to December of previous year/Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I created a pivot table from data that spans from 1/1/2013 to 8/31/2014.  I have a column to compare the difference from previous month, but it will not return a value for January 2014 compared to December 2013.  I have searched for the answer but was unable to find anything that actually resolved the issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The data feeding the pivot table is structured something like this.

```
UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER    DATE    MONTH     YEAR   REVENUE
```

The structure of the pivot table is YEAR and MONTH in the "ROWS" section.  Revenue is summed up in the value section.  Next, I have the sum of revenue calculated as a percentage difference from previous month.  Then I have sum of revenue calculated as a percentage difference from previous year.

Comment: Could you post more information about your actual situation such as formulas and pivot table properties?

Comment: I've provided some additional information to hopefully help you understand the situation.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked almost three (3) years ago but I have came across the same issue recently.

How I solved the problem:

- Added another Column called **MonthID**.  This basically giving months from previous years an accending number

```
2016 Jan to Dec = MonthID: 1-12 
2017 Jan to December = MonthID: 13-24
```

- Used **MonthID** in the Rows Section
- Set Value to % Difference From using **MonthID**

Answer (score 0):

I just come across to have this issue, @Sancho has provided a possible solution but it might not that great if you would like to have dynamic results.

To avoid this, using Year-Month is a good idea, so in that case you can creat a column from your raw data as `=year([your date column])*100 + month([your date column])`

Then you can simply drag this year-month column into the area and problem solved.

You could alter the calculation to have different period analysis, I.e. Quarter? `roundup(month([date])/3,0)` and replace this at the month() section above.